# Show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, P(n) \in \mathbb{Z}$ when $e^{2 i \pi P(n)} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$

Tags: limits, polynomials, integers, roots-of-unity

I want to show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, P(n) \in \mathbb{Z}$, assuming I have both $e^{2 i \pi P(n)} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

My idea was to start doing it by mathematical induction, I write $P = \alpha X^N + Q$ where $\deg Q \leq N-1$. So, if I show that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$, by mathematical induction all coefficients of $P$ will be in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then we'll have the desired result (initialisation is easy).

But I dont't find a way to exploit this track. Any help is welcome.

Comment: The conditions $P\in\Bbb R[x]$ and $P(n)\in\Bbb Z$ wouldn'0t imply that, in fact, $P\in\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: Yes you can reformulate it like that.

Comment: I'll delete my answer, because I misunderstand the question. Sorry.

Comment: Hint: use induction and the fact that $\exp(2i\pi (P(n)-P(n-1))\to 1$ as $n\to +\infty$. This show that $Q(x)=P(x)-P(x-1)$ is such that $Q(n)\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ ; to finish, use that $P(n)=P(0)+Q(1)+...+Q(n)$.

Comment: No Tito, one easy counterexample comes from binomial coefficients : $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is integer valued for every $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: That's it @Kelenner thanks!

Comment: Maybe to give some more perspectives on the answer of Kelenner, if you want to use induction on degree to show a property for every polynomial, you have to find a way to start from a polynomial $P(X)$ of degree $d$ and to obtain a polynomial of degree $d-1$ (or lower). You tried with considering the truncation of $P$, but there are others contruction you can think of better suited for your problem. For exemple $P(X+1) - P(X)$ or $P'(X)$ and others....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Kelenner's hint, if we do it by mathematical induction, we remark that $e^{2 i \pi P(n-1)} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$ then we also have that $e^{2 i \pi (P(n) -P(n-1))} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$. As $Q = P(X) - P(X-1)$ is of degree $< \deg P$, one has $Q(n) \in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

As $P(n) - P(0)= \sum_{k = 1}^n P(k) - P(k-1) = \sum_{k = 1}^n Q(k)$, we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, P(n) - P(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then: $e^{2 i \pi P(0)} = e^{2 i \pi P(n)} e^{- 2 i \pi (P(n) - P(0))}\underset{n \to +\infty} {\longrightarrow} 1 \times 1 = 1$ then $P(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $P(n) = P(0) + Q(1) + \dots + Q(n) \in \mathbb{Z}$.